# webTestCase->drupalPost() or drupal_http_request()?

Tags: testing

I'm writing a simpletest for a module that posts XML directly to a URL (it's on a closed system so there's no user or auth or anything at this point).

I've manually tested getting the response code by using `drupal_http_request()` to POST the file, but since I'm now doing the same thing in an actual simpletest, I feel like I should use `webTestCase->drupalPost()`.

The only problem is that `drupalPost()` seems to expect a save button value. I'm not POSTing via a form with a submit button, so can I still use `drupalPost()`? Or should I just use `drupal_http_request()` in my simpletest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the documentation page for [DrupalWebTestCase::drupalPost()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!simpletest!drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalWebTestCase%3a%3adrupalPost/7), that method supposes to be called for a Drupal page containing a form; if that is not the case, you should use `drupal_http_request()`.

The reason is that the method tries to emulate a click on a submit button, as said in the description for the `$submit` parameter.

> `$submit`: Value of the submit button whose click is to be emulated. For example, `t('Save')`. The processing of the request depends on this value. For example, a form may have one button with the value `t('Save')` and another button with the value `t('Delete')`, and execute different code depending on which one is clicked.

Comment: As well as emulating the submit button it also adds in form id, build id and csrf token (which I just found out before stumbling across this)